# Including seasonal dummies in the augmented Dickey-Fuller test in R

Tags: r, augmented-dickey-fuller

Is there a way to include seasonal dummies when doing the augmented Dickey-Fuller test in R? I have downloaded the "uroot" package but I can only include lags and not seasonal dummies. It seems that the old "uroot" package could do this but the adf test was removed from the "uroot" package for some reason.

Comment: If you can included nonseasonal dummies, can you not slip in seasonal dummies in their place?

Comment: maybe you can, but I don't know how to do it. The function looks like this: ur.df(y, type = c("none", "drift", "trend"), lags = 1, selectlags = c("Fixed", "AIC", "BIC"))

Comment: That function comes from package "urca", not "uroot", and these argument show that there is no place for including dummies (even nonseasonal ones). But try function `CADFtest` from package ["CADFtest"](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/CADFtest/CADFtest.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `CADFtest` from package ["CADFtest"](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/CADFtest/CADFtest.pdf) in R. The dummies can be included via the argument `X` (and they can be generated by, e.g., the function `seasonaldummy` from the "forecast" package). There is also a [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/CADFtest/vignettes/CADFtest.pdf) explaining how to use the package in some detail.